# Не работает скомпилированная программа на C++ на другом компьютере

Tags: c++, opengl, компиляция

У меня есть скомпилированная программа, написанная на C++ (игра на OpenGL). У двух человек на компьютере эта программа запустилась, но на компьютере, который редко используется (в основном, для сёрфинга интернета), появляется консоль и окно игры (как и должно быть), но в консоли, OpenGL выдает ошибки. Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable на этом компьютере установлен, последней версии.

```
ERROR:: SHADER: Compile-time-error:
0(2) : error C0201: unsupported version 460
0(2) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting "::" at token "("
0(4) : warning C7532: global type vec2 requires "#version 100" or later 
0(4) : error C5060: out can't be used with non-varying texCoords
0(6) : warning C7532: global type mat4 requires "#version 100" or later
0(8) : warning C7532: global type float requires "#version 100" or later
0(12) : warning C7532: global variable gl_Position requires "#version 100" or later 
0(12) : warning C7532: global type vec4 requires "#version 100" or later

VERTEX: :SHADER: Compile-time-error
Can't load shader program:
Vertex: res/shaders/vSprite.txt
Fragment: res/shaders/fSprite.txt
```

Comment: Драйвер или карта на новой машине не поддерживают свежую версию шейдеров. Обновите драйвер или карту или оба.

Comment: Скорее понизте версию шейдера, чет я сомневаюсь, что в 460 есть жесткая необходимость.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не поддерживается текущая версия шейдеров, тогда следует поработать с драйверами
Или OpenGL не может справиться с кодировкой, тогда следует изменить кодировку файла шейдеров на utf-8 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713296/c-qt-unsupported-version-error-for-glsl-shader)